# Ansible filter for simple text transforms of lists?

Tags: ansible, ansible-filter

I have an Ansible variable specifing a directory, and another which is a list of files.  I want to derive a list of paths comprised of each file prefixed by the directory.

```
vars:
  dir: /tmp
  files:
  - a
  - b
  - c
  paths: .. # some transform expression
```

The eventual value of `paths` should be as though it had been explicitly defined as

```
  paths:
  - /tmp/a
  - /tmp/b
  - /tmp/c
```

I've tried a solution with `regex_replace`, but that's a pretty nuclear option for such a simple transform, and I ran into endless quoting issues.  I've also tried various combinations with `map`, `join`, `path_join`, and I don't know what-all else.  Some would make perfect sense, if they didn't expect their arguments to be a mix of filter input and actual parameters.

The `regex_replace` example I tried seem to imply that variable definitions could 'forward reference' others in the same `vars` structure, but a few of my attempts gave me pages of errors suggesting that's not [always?] the case.

This is a heavily over-simplified example, and I'm looking for a more general solution than once just for the data shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: ***"I'm looking for a more general solution."***

A: Given the data

```yaml
  dir: /tmp
  files: [a, b, c]
```

1. The standard option is joining the products

```yaml
  paths: "{{ [dir]|product(files)|map('join', '/') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  paths:
    - /tmp/a
    - /tmp/b
    - /tmp/c
```

2. The cutting-edge option is the filter [community.general.path_join](https://ansible.fontein.de/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_paths.html). The below expression gives the same result

```yaml
  paths: "{{ [dir]|product(files)|map('community.general.path_join') }}"
```

3. But, you can easily create a general solution on your own. Write your own filters. For example,

```py
def string_prefix(s, prefix):
    return prefix + str(s)
```

See [string_filters.py](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins/blob/master/filter_plugins/string_filters/string_filters.py). Create directory *plugins/filter* and get the filters

```bash
shell> cd plugins/filter
shell> wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins/master/filter_plugins/string_filters/string_filters.py
```

Configure [DEFAULT_FILTER_PLUGIN_PATH](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-filter-plugin-path)

```bash
shell> pwd
/scratch/tmp7/test-481
shell> ansible-config dump | grep DEFAULT_FILTER_PLUGIN_PATH
DEFAULT_FILTER_PLUGIN_PATH(/export/scratch/tmp7/test-481/ansible.cfg) = ['/scratch/tmp7/test-481/plugins/filter']
```

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── pb.yml
└── plugins
    └── filter
        └── string_filters.py
```

Then, the below expression gives the same result

```yaml
  paths: "{{ files|map('string_prefix', dir ~ '/') }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    dir: /tmp
    files: [a, b, c]

    paths1: "{{ [dir]|product(files)|map('join', '/') }}"
    paths2: "{{ [dir]|product(files)|map('community.general.path_join') }}"
    paths3: "{{ files|map('string_prefix', dir ~ '/') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: paths1
    - debug:
        var: paths2
    - debug:
        var: paths3
```

See an example of other [plugins](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins/tree/master).

Comment: I'm finding the filter syntax incredibly complex and baroque, if powerful, and the documentation lacking and opaque.  I'm not surprised I've been having trouble with, and I thank the random factors for StackExchange and helpful individuals like @vladimir_botka!

I think I'm going to go with custom filters for now, just so my YAML is readable until I'm familiar with the complex syntax.   Docco on writing plugins, and particularly namespacing them (such as `community.general...`) to avoid confusion, is also difficult to find, alas -- but a project for another day.

Comment: See [Creating collections](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_in_groups.html) and [Using collections](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections_guide/index.html) to understand the namespacing. Ultimately, to distribute your stuff, you might want to create your own collection. Meanwhile, for testing or local usage, option 3) requires no namespacing. The first found in DEFAULT_FILTER_PLUGIN_PATH will be used. Thank you for the comment.